# What is the definition of a complementary filter?

Tags: control

This appears to be a general classification of observers, but I can't find it in the index of my applicable texts:

[Mathematical Methods and Algorithims for Signal Processing (Moon and Stirling)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201361868)

[Applied Optimal Estimation (Gelb)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262570483)

If someone can provide a reference to classification of observer, that would be great.

Also, I'm not allowed to create and "estimation" tag, can someone with 300 reputation do that for me? Is there another applicable tag?

Comment: A "Complementary Filter" is when a Diva/Princess only hears the good comments about her, and ignores or doesn't hear the criticisms.

Answer (score 2):

> A pair of filters are called complementary filters if their
>   transfer functions sum to one at all frequencies in a complex
>   sense, i.e. the phase is zero and the magnitude is
>   one.

[source](http://www.ligo.caltech.edu/docs/P/P040020-00.pdf)